# Book Identification: Science Fiction book with Humans in Habitats as Pets : MC Regression

Tags: story-identification

Trying to find this book I read a couple years ago to see if it got a sequel.  In the book a human regresses back in time before the ship he is on is destroyed. Humans are kept in habitats by giant aliens and some of them are used to fight other giant alien's pets.  I vaguely remember there being "Strains" of humans or something to that effect. He is trying to prevent the destruction of the ship while preventing other problems from occurring. Part of the solution to preventing issues is to learn to communicate with the giant alien that owns his habitat.  He fights in the arena several times as well. The book ends after some fight with other aliens attacking his owner's ship.

Any clue what this is?

---

Edit:
As far as the number of humans I do not remember there being more than a couple hundred across a couple of habitats. All of the habitats are on a single ship.  The fights are very much regulated within the ship with the alien "owners" betting on their own fighter. The number of giants I do not remember exactly and I am not sure the book gave a number. The aliens that attacked the ship seemed to be of the same race if I remember right.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How many humans are there?  Are they all from the same ship?  Are they kept together?  Do they have to fight one another?  How many giants are there?  Any distinctive alien races that they fight?